# How To Require A Model Within Another Model's Schema When It Hasn't Been Registered Yet

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Inside the Schema of a Mongoose Model, I need to run a query for another model, but that second Model hasn't been registered yet, resulting in the following error `MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Vote".`  How can I get this to work?

Here is how I bootstrap my models in server.js:

```
//Bootstrap models
var models_path = __dirname + '/app/models';
var walk = function(path) {
    fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(function(file) {
        var newPath = path + '/' + file;
        var stat = fs.statSync(newPath);
        if (stat.isFile()) {
            if (/(.*)\.(js|coffee)/.test(file)) {
                require(newPath);
            }
        } else if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            walk(newPath);
        }
    });
};
walk(models_path);
```

The model starts is called Object, which I believe is being registered before Vote, which might be the problem:

```
// Object Schema
// Module dependencies.
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Vote     = mongoose.model('Vote'),
Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var ObjectSchema = new Schema({
    short_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

ObjectSchema.virtual('voted').get(function () {
  // Here is where I'd like to run a query with the Vote model and then set the virtual attribute either true or false
});
```

Comment: I was just asking the same question, when I noticed this one. I don't suppose you found an answer yet, @ac360?